# Vectorize numpy 1D array function that substracts the next element and adds the previous?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a simple 1D numpy array like the following:

```
np.array([2,1,3,5,1])
```

How can I vectorize a function that, for every element, substracts the next element and adds the previous? In the case above, I would expect something that returns:

```
[?, 1-3+2, 3-5+1, 5-1+3, ?]
=[?, 0, -1, 7, ?]
```

, where ? means I don't care about the element's value. This operation will run in a 1D np.array with 1 million elements (type double).

Comment: Try something like:`a[1:-1]+a[:-2]-a[2:] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, slicing will do what you need:

```
a=np.array([2,1,3,5,1])
print(a[1:-1]+a[:-2]-a[2:])
```

The result will be the array [0,-1,7] with the values you care about.

Comment: I ended up using a convolution which is also a vectorized operation and has a lower memory requirement, but this answer works as well